# Error while publising to docker on Azure from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core website on Azure Docker through visual studio 2015 using [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4) Visual Studio extension. I have tried different approaches but failed to deploy in each one of them.

**Approach 1**
Created a windows docker container directly from Visual studio. In this case the VM was created successfully and I was to able validate the connection successfully before publish.
[image]

However, the publish failed with following error

```
Step 1 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1 Pulling repository
docker.io/microsoft/aspnet Error: image
microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1 not found
```

**Approach 2**
Created a Linux docker container directly from Visual studio. Again, the VM was created successfully and I was able validate the connection successfully before publish. On publishing I got following error:

```
Executing command [docker --tlsverify -H tcp://vmname.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:2376 logs cf32793c88939d664f67c651cbc75c4fb348fdd6fe85ea67322f9b5d049c0e70]
Failed to connect to http://vmname.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/. If your Docker host is an Azure virtual machine, please make sure to set up the endpoint '80' using the Azure portal.
Container logs:
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'MulitvideoMonitoring'.

Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'

 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         Mono
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Linux
 OS Version:   debian 7
 Runtime Id:   ubuntu.14.04-x64


Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
  at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint (System.String applicationName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, System.String appBase, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Approach 3**
Created a classic VM from Azure portal with port 80 opened. On validating the connection it failed. While publishing it could not connect to the VM and gave following error:

```
Executing command [docker --tlsverify -H tcp://vmname.cloudapp.net:2376 ps -a | select-string -pattern ":80->" | foreach { Write-Output $_.ToString().split()[0] }]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(386,5): 
Error : An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://vmname.cloudapp.net:2376/v1.22/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp 23.97.54.64:2376: 
connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Request your help to figure out the issue in the above three approaches.

Comment: A few questions : Is the Docker Daemon listening on the tcp endpoint?
if you ssh into the docker host and execute "docker -H tcp://vmname.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:2376 ps" does it work? Is the tcp port the docker daemon is listening on accessible from outside?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue on my Linux VM. The issue was due to the wrong runtime in dockerfile. The auto-generated dockerfile from Visual Studio tooling had wrong runtime causing the issue.
The dockerfile had runtime `FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1` changing it to `microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr` resolved the issue. I got the tip from an answer to similar question raised by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302097/asp-net-core-issues-while-debugging-through-docker-in-visual-studio-2015/36378460#36378460).