# To understand ENTRYPOINT in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am going to push my asp.net core 1.0 code from Windows environment to remote Linux docker container. Basically the container will host the application as the server.

Now I see the different configuration for ENTRYPOINT in different blogs.

1. `ENTRYPOINT ["./kestrel"]` at http://blog.dudak.me/2015/deploying-aspnet-5-applications-to-docker-containers/
2. `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]` at [Cannot run asp.net 5 from docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977474/cannot-run-asp-net-5-from-docker)
3. `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "./src/HelloMvc6", "kestrel"]` at https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime/
4. `ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]` if using http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx

I am new to docker. I don't know the differences and not sure which one can be used.

Comment: You have just posted a list of random commands.  I would suggest starting with [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), and then asking specific questions about things that aren't clear.

Comment: Entrypoint is just the command to run when docker starts. The examples you listed are more or less the same. No. 1 and 4 `kestrel` and `web` are themselves a shell script that if you open, you'll find the same `dnx ....` command. You might want to research how to properly use this command.

Comment: @warmoverflow, for No. 4. Why use `web`? Is it a special word? I can't find the document for that. It is a command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are various commands from `project.json` or scripts that invoke commands in `project.json`.

If you look at [a project.json file](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/MusicStore/project.json#L45-L51) you'll see a list of commands like:

```
"commands": {
  "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration",
  "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:5003",
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004",
  "weblistener": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5002"
},
```

Also, when you publish an application, a script with the commands name will be generated. For example, for `kestrel` dnx will generate `kestrel` (unix) and `kestrel.cmd` (windows) which simply invokes `dnx` with the argument `kestrel`.

`-p` passed to `dnx` specifies the project to run. In newer versions of `dnx` you don't need `-p`; instead the first argument passed is the project path.

So, in your case:

1. `ENTRYPOINT ["./kestrel"]` is the script that invokes `dnx . kestrel` or `dnx kestrel`.
2. `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]` invokes `dnx` with the arguments `-p project.json web` (the web command).
3. `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "./src/HelloMvc6", "kestrel"]` same as 2 but the `kestrel` command.
4. `ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]` same as 1, invokes the script that calls the `web` command.

Comment: Thanks. A follow question. From [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/02/19/developing-asp-net-apps-in-docker-containers/), it used a different one `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "dnx-watch web"]`. When we deploy an asp.net to a docker container, should we use this one or pick up any one from my original `ENTRYPOINT` list of 1,2,3 and 4?

Comment: `dnx-watch` is usually a development scenario because require you to deploy the source code too. That's nice when you develop and change code because your app will restart when a file changes but in a production scenario where files don't change, you don't need that.