# Docker didn't forward the port from web service

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I'm using ASP Core image to create a new container.

I've developed simple service which uses port `5000`.

Now I created Dockerfile and built container which exposes

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

Running this container with a command

```
docker run -it -p 8080:5000 <name>
```

or even

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:5000 <name>
```

doesn't lead to navigation to the `127.0.0.1:8080`. So my browser says `this site can't be reached`.

p.s. I've checked the service without docker - it works correctly

**UPD1**

```
docker ps
```

shows my launched container with ports mapping information:

```
127.0.0.1:8080->5000/tcp
```

**UPD2**

this is `netstat` output from the host

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:5000          *:*                     LISTEN
```

`lynx 127.0.0.1:5000` shows `200 OK`

`netstat -a` on a client box doesn't show `8081` port or `5000`

**UPD3**

I've just created a new container for NodeJs using public image.

Created a simple server with exposed port. After running it works as expected.

Actually it looks like the problem with exact Asp image

Comment: Did you check the servise within docker?

Comment: could you please advice how to do that?

Comment: You can run: sudo docker exec -i -t <docker id> /bin/bash

Comment: How do you know your service is actually working? Did you try `docker logs your-instance-name`?

Comment: I see output forwarding from container. And I see that my service started without any issues on specified port. Actually the same information without docker leads to correct execution

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It says "Error: No such container". But I've just connected there via bash

Comment: You need to give it the _container id_ not the image name. The container id is the first column when you do `docker ps`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes you're right. I received the same output I've already described - there are no errors

Comment: print out once you check with this command `lynx 127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: this returns 200. actually i have angular2 simple app, which was not loaded but lynx. but lynx returns 200 OK. This all about lynx oh the host, not client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run asp.net 5 from docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977474/cannot-run-asp-net-5-from-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? If you're running on OSX or Windows you will need to use the IP of your boot2docker virtual machine, not 127.0.0.1.

`docker-machine ip` will show you the IP of your current host.

Comment: I'm launching on Windows. i've already tried this IP address too. and I've tried to forward to 127.0,0,1

Comment: What does ```docker-machine ls``` show you? If there is more than one machine you could be launching on one and trying to access another. If there is just one what does ```docker-machine ip``` show you? Can you ping that address?

Comment: there is only one box is ls. yes, I can ping it